# Passing an unevaluated test

Tags: evaluation, options

I want to write a function (in a package) that takes a boolean test as an option.  Here's a toy example to illustrate what I have in mind:

```
func[a_, b_, c_, opts___?OptionQ] := Module[{test, sol},
   test = Evaluate[Test /. Flatten[{opts, Options[func]}]];
   sol = Solve[a x^2 + b x + c == 0, x];
   If[Evaluate[test /. Global`sol -> sol], Print["test true"]];
   Return[sol]
];
Options[func] = {Test -> False};
```

Then

```
func[1, 2, 3, Test -> (Re[x /. sol[[1]]]) < 0]
```

should print "test true", but doesn't.

If I use a different dummy name instead of `sol`, it works as expected

```
func[a_, b_, c_, opts___?OptionQ] := Module[{test, sol},
   test = Evaluate[Test /. Flatten[{opts, Options[func]}]];
   sol = Solve[a x^2 + b x + c == 0, x];
   If[Evaluate[test /. foo -> sol], Print["test true"]];
   Return[sol]
];
func[1, 2, 3, Test -> (Re[x /. foo[[1]]]) < 0]
(* "test true " *)
```

but also throws `Part::partd` and `ReplaceAll::reps` errors.

How can I get this to work using the name `sol` when calling my function and avoid those errors?

Comment: I think that you are thinking that the "local" `sol` isn't in the `Global` context, but it is. You haven't changed the context, so `Global``sol` and `sol` are the same symbol. Maybe look at this: http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/NamespaceManagement.html

Comment: There are several other unnecessary complexities with your code. A better signature would probably be `func[a_, b_, c_, opts : OptionsPattern[]]`. Then you can get the value for the `Test` option like this `test = OptionValue[Test]`. You don't need an explicit `Return`. You also don't need to use `Evaluate`.

Comment: More abstractly, your strategy here is coupling internal symbol names within your function to the symbols passed in as part of the `Test` option. And since you've hard-coded the equation you're solving, this whole approach seems overly complicated. Maybe some of your context has been lost in creating this toy problem, but as it stands, it's very difficult to understand why you're trying to do it this way.

Comment: @lericr Thanks for the thoughts! The ``Global``` may be a holdover from my real problem, which lives in a package with its own context. As for `OptionsPattern` and `Return`, I claim personal "style" ;) -- I started with the old-fashioned option-handling form and just like the explicit `Return` to highlight for myself what's returned.  The main issue is that the `sol` that I want the test to look at is indeed hardcoded with that name (the real `sol` comes from `NDSolve`).